# Rectangle not showing on canvas

Tags: javascript, draw, rectangles

I am trying to create a program that makes an orange birthday cake with purple icing, red candles, and a blue plate but the candles aren't showing. could anyone help? The candles are supposed to be rectangles.

Thanks!
-Lerb_games

P.s. here is the code:

```
var CENTER_X = getWidth() / 2;
var CENTER_Y = getHeight() / 2;
println(CENTER_X + ", " + CENTER_Y);
var CAKE_WIDTH = 200; //Tens has to be even
var CAKE_HEIGHT = 100; //Tens has to be even
var CAKE_COLOR = "orange";
var ICING_RADIUS = 10;
var NUM_ICING = CAKE_WIDTH / (ICING_RADIUS * 2);
var ICING_COLOR = "purple";
while (!(NUM_CANDLES > 0)){
    var NUM_CANDLES = readLine("How old are you? ");
    if (NUM_CANDLES > 0){
        break;
    } else{
        while (!(NUM_CANDLES > 0)){
            NUM_CANDLES = readInt("That was not an integer, please try again. How old are you? ");
            if (NUM_CANDLES > 0){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
var CANDLE_WIDTH = NUM_CANDLES / 15;
var CANDLE_HEIGHT = NUM_CANDLES / 10;
var CANDLE_COLOR = "#9B30FF";
var PLATE_WIDTH = CAKE_WIDTH + 50;
var PLATE_HEIGHT = 50;
var PLATE_COLOR = "blue";

function start() {
    var cake = new Rectangle(CAKE_WIDTH, CAKE_HEIGHT);
    cake.setPosition(CENTER_X - (CAKE_WIDTH / 2), CENTER_Y - (CAKE_HEIGHT / 2));
    cake.setColor(CAKE_COLOR);
    add(cake);

    var plate = new Rectangle(PLATE_WIDTH, PLATE_HEIGHT);
    plate.setPosition((CENTER_X - (CAKE_WIDTH / 2)) - ((PLATE_WIDTH % CAKE_WIDTH) / 2), CENTER_Y + (CAKE_HEIGHT / 2));
    plate.setColor(PLATE_COLOR);
    add(plate);

    for (var i = 0; i <= NUM_CANDLES; i++){
        var candles = new Rectangle(CANDLE_WIDTH, CANDLE_HEIGHT);
        candles.setPosition(CENTER_X - (CAKE_WIDTH / 2), (CENTER_Y + (CAKE_HEIGHT / 2)) + ((CANDLE_HEIGHT % CAKE_HEIGHT) / 2));
        candles.setColor(CANDLE_COLOR);
        add(candles);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i <= NUM_ICING; i++){
        var icing = new Circle(ICING_RADIUS);
        icing.setPosition(CENTER_X - (CAKE_WIDTH / 2), CENTER_Y - (CAKE_HEIGHT / 2));
        icing.move((ICING_RADIUS * 2) * i, 0)
        icing.setColor(ICING_COLOR);
        add(icing);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i <= NUM_ICING; i++){
        var icing = new Circle(ICING_RADIUS);
        icing.setPosition(CENTER_X - (CAKE_WIDTH / 2), CENTER_Y + (CAKE_HEIGHT / 2));
        icing.move((ICING_RADIUS * 2) * i, 0)
        icing.setColor(ICING_COLOR);
        add(icing);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using any libraries or frameworks?

Comment: No? I am not...

Comment: Where is `getWidth`, `readLine`, `readInt`, `Rectangle`, `Circle`, etc comming from?

Comment: If you're **only** using JavaScript (no libraries), your code is missing a lot of reproducible components: `getWidth()`, `getHeight()`, `println(string)`, `readLine(string)`, `readInt(string)`, `class Rectangle`, `add(object)`, and `class Circle`. Performing a search of **all** these terms gave me a result where this code works without modification on [CodeHS](https://codehs.com/sandbox/id/lerb-games-school-alt-example-bX9e7Q). Is [CodeHS](https://codehs.com/) where you are running/developing your code?